# What type is this ((UIView & MDCTextInput)?)?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to swift and I've encountered this weird type when using a material components library.
What type is this?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGS9.png)

`(UIView & MDCTextInput)?` It looks like a inout MDCTextInput inside a optional tuple? But what's with the "UIView" in front of the rest?
I have no idea what I should put in there as I don't know what type it is

Comment: It means that the parameters needs to be a `UIView` and that needs to be compliant to protocol `MDCTextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `UIView` that also conforms to the protocol `MDCTextInput`. And it's an optional value.

Basically something that looks like this:

```
class MyView: UIView, MDCTextInput {
...
```